# How is inline feedback implemented on google support?

Tags: html, forms, user-feedback

The Google support site has a capability to provide feedback on precise segments of answers by hovering over the right border and clicking the icon. Example : https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9739231

Image below:

[image: Google Support Feedback image]

Clicking the icon prompts the user to describe what needs improvement about this highlighted section.

Are there any libraries, how-to-guides, or terms that can be used to find out more about how this is implemented? I am interested in the full lifecycle of this operation: UI, backend, metrics, anything.

The goal is to use a similar mechanism for our own services. For example, if we provide a data dictionary, and someone thinks a definition is wrong, we want to permit feedback and start corrective action.

The HTML elements use 'inline feedback' as component names or classes frequently. Searching for this has not been fruitful.

My thought would be that div elements are identified by id attrs, and the submitted form includes the id. But the highlighted segments don't seem to have identifiers.